# PHP Class problems

Tags: php, class, notifications

I'm having troubles with this classes in PHP...

What I want is a "notification" system across my whole website - however this script only works when everything is in one file. How can I fix this.

```
class Message  {

    var $message; // A variable to store a list of messages

    // Return a string containing a list of messages found,
    function listMessages($delim = ' '){
        if (count($this->message) > 0){
            echo implode($delim,$this->message);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Manually add Message
    function addMessage($description){
        $this->message[] = $description;
    }       
}
$message = new Message();

$message->addMessage('Article Title 1');
$message->addMessage('Article Title 2');

$message->listMessages();
```

Comment: Are there any errors when everything isn't in one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`include_once`](http://ca.php.net/include_once) function. Essentially, you want to have each of your classes in their own separate file, and then when you want to use them, you call `include_once("thatfile.php");` to make that class accessible to your application.

I should clarify that you should use `include_once` (or [`require_once`](http://ca.php.net/require_once) if you would prefer) over `include` because if you include your class file twice, you'll get errors saying you're trying to define a class that already exists.

Using your example, your program would look like this:

**MessageClass.php**

```
<?php
class Message  {

  public $message;

  // Return a string containing a list of messages found
  public function listMessages($delim = ' '){
      if (count($this->message) > 0){
          echo implode($delim,$this->message);
      }else{
          return false;
      }
  }

  // Manually add Message
  public function addMessage($description){
      $this->message[] = $description;
  } 
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

include_once("MessageClass.php");

$message = new Message();
$message->addMessage('Article Title 1'); $message->addMessage('Article Title 2');
$message->listMessages();
```

Also notice that I changed your class variables (members) and functions (methods) to include the `public` modifier. I'm not 100% sure about how it works in PHP, but in most languages these things tend to be `private` by default, meaning they can't be accessed from outside of the class. It's always better to include them to be clear.

You might also want to look into the [`__autoload()`](http://ca.php.net/__autoload) function, which is called whenever you try to use a class which hasn't yet been defined. In this function, which you define yourself, you can figure out in which file a given class resides, and `include_once` it automatically when you need it. More generally, you should look into the [`spl_autoload_register`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function, which is the same thing but with a lot more flexibility.

Comment: your copy-paste kung-fu is stronger then mine.

Comment: I've been using includes...maybe its the way the system was set up.

Comment: It depends on what you want really.

Answer (score 1):

If you want these messages to be viewable across all pages on your site, then you need to store them somewhere permanent. Anything you put in a PHP variable ceases to exist after each page request. Put the messages in a file or a database, and read them from the database when you instantiate your Message object.

Comment: Ok so if I understand you right...
If all the files are included in say "index.php" the message won't be viewable in file 2 even if it was called in file one because the variable isn't transfered?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question. You can put the code wherever you want. You can use your message class everywhere, on every page of your site. But if you're just going to hard code the messages into the file, why are you creating this class at all?

Answer (score 1):

you can create one class file where this class are situated with its all methods then you have to include this class file in the all file where you want to use this class and methods.
and then you can use this class with the create an object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, multiple files can be made to work together using [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[`require`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and their cousins [`include_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)/[`require_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php). Let me demonstrate by example. You can break things up into multiple files as follows; Put the class in a file called `Message.php` which might look like this:

```
<?php

class Message  {

    var $message; // A variable to store a list of messages

    // Return a string containing a list of messages found,
    function listMessages($delim = ' '){
        if (count($this->message) > 0){
            echo implode($delim,$this->message);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Manually add Message
    function addMessage($description){
        $this->message[] = $description;
    }       
}

?>
```

And include it in another file, in the same directory called `notification.php` which might look like this.

```
<?php

require_once 'Message.php';

$message = new Message();

$message->addMessage('Article Title 1');
$message->addMessage('Article Title 2');

$message->listMessages();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting your class into a seperate file

-- class.Message.php -----

```
var $message; // A variable to store a list of messages

// Return a string containing a list of messages found,
function listMessages($delim = ' '){
    if (count($this->message) > 0){
        echo implode($delim,$this->message);
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

// Manually add Message
function addMessage($description){
    $this->message[] = $description;
}       
}
```

?>

---- end class -----

--- testPageMessage.php -----

```
<?php 

require_once('class.Message.php');

$message = new Message();

$message->addMessage('Article Title 1');
$message->addMessage('Article Title 2');

$message->listMessages();

?>
```

---- end test page -----

On a side note you may want require or include. The difference being:
REQUIRE will throw an exception if not found.
INCLUDE will throw a warning if not found.

The _ONCE (Require_once or Include_once) will make sure the file is only included once. (as opposed to multiple times)

Comment: Alright...So I've got it working now BUT.... when I want to have "listMessage" called in footer.php and "addMessage" called in header nothing is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Although, its not entirely clear from your question that the following solution may be of use, but try calling the last four lines in the `footer` file (which is included in every page), if you've it..

```
$message = new Message();

$message->addMessage('Article Title 1');
$message->addMessage('Article Title 2');

$message->listMessages();
```